# Page transitions in Angular 2

Tags: angular, css-animations

since angular 2 animations are not yet totally updated, is there any way to animate page with css?

I tried with adding host in component but that wasnt helpfull.

For example this is my component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'pos-projects-list',
    pipes: [AsyncPipe, SearchPipe],
    directives: [RippleDirective],
    templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/pages/projects/templates/list.html',
    host: {'class' : 'ng-animate'}
})
```

So what i am doing here is adding class to pos-projects-list which you can see in screenshot.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi00m.png)

Comment: More details please. What's the code of the `component` you are trying to animate?

Comment: I am trying to animate anything which is dynamic on site, for example pos-projects-list, look at the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The regular CSS animation will work fine:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

**Update**: The actual question is "How to change class of host element?"

Here is the example:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'pos-projects-list',
   host: {'[class.ng-animate]':'someField'}
})
export class PosProjectListComponent implement AfterViewInit {
  someField: bool = false;

  // alternative way
  // @HostBinding('class.ng-animate') someField: bool = false;
  // -----------------------

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    someField = true; // set class `ng-animate` on `<pos-projects-list>`
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem isnt css3 animations, the problem is how can i append class to router-outlet to initialize that animation?

Comment: This is the error which i get: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'

Comment: Try setting `someField = true` in a function which is a callback to something (button click, timer). Also I'd create your example in https://plnkr.co/